# Wordpress notification emails going to spam

Tags: wordpress, email, spam

How can I prevent Worpress notification e-mails from going to recipients' spam folders?

I have set up a site along with its blog in three different environments as follows (I'm using "mydomain.com" instead of the actual site's domain for confidentiality reasons).

1. `local.mydomain.com` and `blog.local.mydomain.com` on my machine
2. `dev.mydomain.com` and `blog.dev.mydomain.com` on my dev server
3. `mydomain.com` and `blog.mydomain.com` on production server

When I create users in 1 and 2 (local and dev), notification e-mails go to the inboxes of the newly created users. But when I do the same in production, they go straight to the spam folders.

Now, by default Wordpress notifications are sent from `wordpress@yourblogsdomain.com`, so in my case, these were sent by `wordpress@blog.mydomain.com`, `wordpress@blog.dev.mydomain.com` and `wordpress@blog.local.mydomain.com`. So I installed the [Mail From Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mail-from/) to change the default address, and now all three servers are sending the messages from `hello@mydomain.com`, which is an existing and working address.

mydomain.com e-mails are managed by Google Accounts, that's working fine, ie, messages sent from @mydomain.com accounts are received as not-spam messages. That's including that `hello@mydomain.com` address.

All this leaves me thinking there might be something wrong with the server that's hosting my production site, but I have no idea where to start looking.

Thoughts?

Comment: "How can I prevent Worpress notification e-mails from going to recipients' spam folders?". I'm pretty sure that there isn't 100% guarantee on this.

Comment: Well, yeah, I know that, but it's still weird that a new domain, with no history of spamming whatsoever, is presenting these issues... and only when sent from a specific server! I'm pretty sure that in this case is something I can avoid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I usually handle this on the server level by ensuring all emails sent by wordpress are sent via my own SMTP server. You can do this a couple ways. My preference is to configure all mail being sent from my server to use SMTP. I usually use an Ubuntu server - here is a link to using PostFix SMTP https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix. Another way would be to use one of the SMTP plugins and configure to use your email server.I have used this one in the past - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/screenshots/.

Answer (score 0):

Its work definitely

Please use this code its help you:-

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', 'my_mail_from' );
                function my_mail_from( $email ) {
                    return "enter yout 'from' id";
                }

                add_filter('wp_mail_from_name', 'new_mail_from_name');
                function new_mail_from_name($old) {
                    return 'enter your "from name"';
                }
       wp_mail( $admin_mail, $subject, $message );
```