# Contact Form 7 mail is not sending

Tags: wordpress

When I use Contact form 7 no errors are happening but the mail is not sending.I used valid email id as administrator mail id.Then also mail is not going.

Then I installed WP-Mail-SMTP plugin.Now the following error is displayed :
"Failed to send your message. Please try later or contact the administrator by another method."

When  I use FormGet plug in mail had sent properly.

Pls help me :(

Answer (score 0):

If you get successful message from Contact Form 7 like 'Your message sent successfully' then message must be in Spam folder. To fix this you should set at least FROM address for emails.

In your function.php

```
add_filter('wp_mail_from', 'cdx_from_email');
function cdx_from_email() {
  return "smth@yourdomain.com";
}
```

Comment: After using this code also mail is coming in spam folder.Why??

Comment: Make sure you use your domain name. Here are some suggestions as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497048/wordpress-notification-emails-going-to-spam

Comment: my domain name is **meenu.mypenguin.in**