# wordpress email sending to spam folder

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am a WordPress developer since 3 years, I worked for
http://fort.parksandbraxton.com/
http://tampa.parksandbraxton.com/

I worked for above 2 wordpress websites, I used contact from 7 ,but every time when a website visitor was sending email through contact form, it was going to spam folder. I used others plugin like fromcraft3 instead of contact from 7. That was sending email to spam folder too. Is that host gator server issue or subdomain issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wordpress notification emails going to spam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497048/wordpress-notification-emails-going-to-spam)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hostgator would most likely be the issue. Assumign you're on a shared hosting plan, someone else on the account is probably sending out spam via the server and got the IP address flagged for spam.

Try sending email using SMTP rather than using the php mail() function.

Comment: http://jacksonville.parksandbraxton.com/ it is custom php website, i used there php mail function it was working fine. so it was wp-mail issue or sever flagged the ip address as for wp mail?

Comment: Does this occur with Hotmail specifically or all major mail providers?

Comment: All major mail like gmail and others email too.

Comment: Are you able to edit your post to include the mailing code? Does it have a replyto mail set?

wp_mail uses PHPMailer, this post might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302962/mail-delivered-as-spam-phpmailer-how-to-avoid

Comment: I got the solution, it was the server issue.